# Vertical Menu with Show and hide by Arrow image

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I am newbie to web so, now am trying to create a menu with Arrow mark image to show/hide by clicking of image in vertical menu. Now I tried like below to click of menu it working but I have to show as like image :                                                               [image]

```
  A
    --a
    --C
    ...D
  B
    --f
    --g
    ..i
```

Comment: k wait i will make simple demo example

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jnqDh/)  Look at this demo link

Comment: you want to show as like image means? I saw your fiddle, but dint get ur question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial for that using CSS/HTML5, just click the link [Hide/Show Menu CSS3/HTML5](http://www.webtutorialsource.com/tutorial/show-hide-toggle-sliding-menu-css-javascript/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="box" class="hide">
<ul id="tab">
    <li>
        <img id="arrow" onclick="toggle('box');" src="/images/arrowleft.png">
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="links">
    <div id="deco">
        <div class="bt"><a href="index.php" >HOME</a></div>
        <div class="bt"><a href="tut.php" >TUTS</a></div>
        <div class="bt"><a href="about.php" >ABOUT</a></div>
        <div class="bt"><a href="contact.php" >CONTACT</a></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box{
width: 190px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
right: -140px;
top: 25%; /* change this value to place the menu higher or lower */
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
}

#tab{
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}

#tab li span{
display: block;
padding: 0 5px;
position: relative;
}

#links{
width: 80px;
padding: 10px;
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #B4B8BB;
}

.show, .hide{
/* we specify the transition length for hiding and showing */
        transition: margin-right .4s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: margin-right .4s ease-in;
}

.hide{
margin-right:0px;
}

.show{
margin-right:95px;
}

#arrow, .bt{
cursor: pointer;
}

.bt{
width: 77px;
height: 40px;
margin: -1px;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #858fa6;
font: bold 13px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
background:#014464;
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1F82AF, #002F44);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1F82AF, #002F44);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1F82AF, #002F44);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1F82AF, #002F44);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#1F82AF),    to(#002F44));
}

.bt a{
line-height: 40px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
}

.bt:hover{
transition: background .3s linear;
background: #32A3D3;
-o-transition: background .3s linear;
-moz-transition: background .3s linear;
-webkit-transition: background .3s linear;
}

#deco{
width: 75px;
float: left;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function toggle(id) {
var el = document.getElementById(id);
var img = document.getElementById("arrow");
var box = el.getAttribute("class");
if(box == "hide"){
    el.setAttribute("class", "show");
    delay(img, "/images/arrowright.png", 400);
  }
else{
    el.setAttribute("class", "hide");
    delay(img, "/images/arrowleft.png", 400);
   }
}

function delay(elem, src, delayTime){
 window.setTimeout(function() {elem.setAttribute("src", src);}, delayTime);
}
```

Comment: I had look at the link it occupy a full page but am trying to achieve as like above image Reason is user wants to see a content for full page at the time he can click at the arrow  it will hide menu and show content in full page

Comment: You can customize the Menu to be a smaller size as you wish

Comment: i will try as my level

Comment: Do u look at the Demo link i had created Vertical menu ..now i want to add arrow image for Show and hide if u can help on this??

Comment: The best way to learn is to always try your hands on sample tutorials, you can then build your own or customize the codes.

Comment: @user3331535 I now understand your question and a sample code have being provided too

Comment: @user3331535 you are welcome. If it answers your question, just choose it as your answer